# Jenkins groovy - copy file based on string in params

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job where that needs to copy a file to a specific server per user choice.  Till today all was working since I needed to copy the same file to the server that the user choose.

Now I need to copy a specific file per server. I n case the user chooses to deploy Server_**lab1**-1.1.1.1 so **lab1**.file.conf file should be copied.  in case the user chooses to deploy Server_**lab2**-2.2.2.2 , **lab2**.file.conf should be copied.

I’m guessing that I need to add to the function
Check if the Server parameter includes lab1 if so, copy lab1.file.conf file and if the Server parameter includes lab2 if so, copy lab2.file.conf file

```
parameters {
        extendedChoice(name: 'Servers', description: 'Select servers for deployment', multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
                type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'Server_lab1-1.1.1.1, Server_lab2-2.2.2.2', visibleItemCount: 5)

stage ('Copy nifi.flow.properties file') {
            steps {  copy_file()  }  }

def copy_file() {
    params.Servers.split(',').each { item -> server = item.split('-').last()
        sh "scp **lab1.file.conf or lab2.file.conf** ${ssh_user_name}@${server}:${spath}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below.

```
def copy_file() {
    params.Servers.split(',').each { item ->     
    def server = item.split('-').last()
    def fileName = item.contains('lab1') ? 'lab1.file' : 'lab2.file'
    sh "scp ${fileName} ${ssh_user_name}@${server}:${spath}"
    }
}
```

**Update** Classic if-else

```
def copy_file() {
    params.Servers.split(',').each { item ->     
    def server = item.split('-').last()
    def fileName = "default"
    if(  item.contains('lab1')) {
        fileName = 'lab1.file'
    } else if(item.contains('lab2')) {
        fileName = 'lab2.file'
    } else if(item.contains('lab3')) {
        fileName = 'lab3.file'
    }    
    sh "scp ${fileName} ${ssh_user_name}@${server}:${spath}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it - I need to try it.  But if i have 3 files Lab1, Lab2 & Lab3 so how can i have if Lab1 -- > lab1.file  if lab2 --> lab2.file if lab3 --> lab3.file

Comment: @dzbeda you can use classic if-else statements for that. Check the update.